# PHP / HTML: Import HTML file into another one, while merging duplicates

Tags: php, html, include

First of all, I know that there are many questions leading towards including HTML.

The thing is, when I include one HTML (1) file into another (2), using `<?php include("1.html") ?>`, and both files consist of something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="specific div">
            <span id="span1">1</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Having two different spans in the same specific div - once I include one file into the other one, it would look like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="specific div">
            <span id="span1">1</span>
        </div>
        <div id="specific div">
            <span id="span2">2</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

while I want the contents of the `specific div` merged into one of them, instead of having to divs with the same `id` in the end:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="specific div">
            <span id="span1">1</span>
            <span id="span2">2</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I achieve that?

---

**EDIT:** I found a different and less complicated solution for my specific situation. Therefore I can't really select the correct answer now, so I might select one if it gets enough upvotes.

Comment: Do those includes actually have begin and end html and body tags too? Or are they simply html pieces (without full page wrappings)?

Comment: They are fully functional HTML files with <html> and <body> tags, just as shown above. You should also note, that both the <html> and <body> tags are merged instead of being duplicated. So that's pretty much what I want to happen with the specific div aswell...

Comment: You can either use iframe or convert your html files to php

Comment: You really should post what solution you went with. The point of keeping a question up on stackoverflow, is so others can find solutions through searches. Seeing what YOU went with, is helpful information (post it as your own answer to the question).

Comment: I just removed the specific div in the imported file, and put span1 into the other files where required. That is nowhere a solution to the problem described above, but just for my specific situation...

Answer (score 2):

You could use php's [`DomDocument::loadHTMLFile()`](http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) function. With this you can load both of your files and merge them the way you like it.

If your file looks like you said, something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="specific div1">
            <span id="span">bla bla bla</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can use the `DomDocument`:

```
$dom1 = new DomDocument();
$dom1->loadHTMLFile("file_1.html", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$dom2 = new DomDocument();
$dom2->loadHTMLFile("file_2.html", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$element = $dom2->getElementById("specific div2")->firstChild;
$dom1->getElementById("specific div1")->appendChild($element);

$merged_html = $dom1->saveHTML()
```

So this would merge the contents of the `div[id="specific div2"]` to the `div[id="specific div1"]`

`DOMDocument` also supports xpath if you like it more than going through the nodes maually or selecting by id.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is no longer existent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include one html file to another then you can either use iframe or can convert the files to php as well to use include.

Like if you want to include index2.html in index1.html then you can use below iframe code in index1.html:

index1.html

```
<iframe src="index2.html"></iframe>
```

Or you can convert your files to PHP and then simply include one file to other like below:

index1.php

```
<?php include('index2.php'); ?>
```

You can also use **[Server Side Include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html)** like below to include one html to another:

index1.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <!--#include virtual="/index2.html" -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is no longer existent.